# Running Python Splunk SDK Test Suite

Tags: python, splunk

I'm trying to run the Splunk python sdk test suite and running into connection errors.

I access splunk via `company`.splunkcloud.net and name@company.com/password for credentials. I'm not entirely sure what should be in my .splunkrc, is the localhost they refer to the agent?

I'm a little lost. Any advice on what's required to run the test suite is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Splunk Enterprise or Splunk Cloud?

If you're using Splunk Enterprise, you can test your credentials over curl like so:

```
curl -k -u name@company.com:changeme https://localhost:8089/services/server/info/server-info
```

I believe port 8089, the REST API port, is blocked in Splunk Cloud by default so the Python SDK won't be able to connect to it. I would contact support and see if they can unblock the port for you.

Your .splunkrc file should look something like this

```
host=company.splunkcloud.net
port=8089
username=name@company.com
password=changeme
scheme=https
```

Comment: I'm on splunkcloud, I've opened a support ticket to get the port opened so we'll see if that does it. Thank you!